# Cassandra: Proper way to drop keyspace and create again

Tags: cassandra-2.0, cassandra-2.1

I am working with five node Cassandra cluster. Recently i dropped the keyspace and create it again. My application failed to read particular column family after this and saw tombstone failure threshold so, I run the compaction command on the whole keyspace still seeing same error in the log file and the page cannot read the file. Any suggestions or solution

Comment: Can you provide relevant logs and error messages?

Comment: Eventually it got fixed after several nodetool repair